# How to install requirements.txt file from a python module?

Tags: python, installation, pip, requirements.txt

I am looking for an alternative to

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

which can be used to install packages from a python module. I  have used

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
```

for installing a package, however, this command seems to work only for a single package. Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with `pip install -r requirements.txt` for you?

Comment: pip install -r requirements.txt works without any issues, I just could not find an alternative  way of installing multiple packages, which I guess would make the code a bit more modular in my case.

Comment: Sorry, can you unpack "I just could not find an alternative way of installing multiple packages, which I guess would make the code a bit more modular in my case"?

Comment: Sure. I could not get the following code to work for me, which works fine with a single package name specified. 

import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "requirements.txt"]).

I am looking for an alternative to install the requirements from a python script without using the pip command.

Comment: Right, but Gabip was asking what's wrong with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. What is your motivation to install "without using the pip command"? And why from a Python script? Why do you want an alternative in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't forget to replace "package" with "-r requirements.txt":

```py
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"])
```

Comment: This approach somehow does not work for me even with the correctly specified directory.

Comment: @karen-gishyann What kind of error message do you get?

Comment: this is the error.

Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'requirements.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: @karen-gishyann Try capturing the output message to identify the underlying error: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: @karen-gishyann Like such: https://pastebin.com/KHWpTusM

Comment: JBen it says no matching distribution found for requirements.txt, if I get it to work, will update. thanks.

Comment: @karen-gishyann You are still omitting the "-r" switch from after "install", without the switch it tries to install a package called "requirements.txt" instead of installing its contents.

Comment: Jben, I think you are right, thus the answer is the solution. I had not looked at it carefully, thanks!!